# How to reference object by name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

```
$.getScript(app.modulePath+'/'+ moduleName+'.js')   //include file
    .done(function()
{
    app.loadedModules.push(moduleName);             //track loaded modules
    app.currentModule = moduleName;                 //assign module name to object property
});
```

I am loading javascript modules as I need them, but am having trouble referencing them.
To load the module by name, I use a string and assign the string as the currentModule. But it's a string. How to I assign the loaded object which has the same name as the string.

**Example:**

**Images.js**

```
var Images = (function()
{

 return {
    allImages: function(){},
    oneImage: function(){}
 };

});
```

---

**app.js**

```
var moduleName = 'Images';
$.getScript(moduleName).done(function()
{
   myApp.currentModule = moduleName;
   //how to reference currentModule as object
});
```

Comment: i think what you are looking for is require.js

Comment: You can use [http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)

Comment: I'll be honest, I get what require.js is for, which is my situation here but its really hard to use. I'll consider it after I get a little further. Thanks.

Comment: @Sacreyoule Suggesting `eval` with a link from [w3schools](http://w3fools.com). That's some truly high level advice you've given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the global object:

```
window[moduleName].allImages();
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand your problem is creating the module object and assgin it right ? If im mistaken let me know in comments

So here is the soltion to your problem

**app.js**

```
var moduleName = 'Images';
$.getScript(moduleName+'.js').done(function()
{
   myApp.currentModule = new window[moduleName]();
   console.log(myApp.currentModule)
});
```